# Why is Async version slower than single threaded version?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am reading a large XML file using XmlReader and am exploring potential performance improvements via Async & pipelining. The following initial foray into the world of Async is showing that the Async version (which for all intents and purposes at this point is the equivalent of the Synchronous version) is much slower. **Why would this be?** All I've done is wrapped the "normal" code in an Async block and called it with `Async.RunSynchronously`

## Code

```
open System
open System.IO.Compression  // support assembly required + FileSystem
open System.Xml             // support assembly required


let readerNormal (reader:XmlReader) = 
    let temp = ResizeArray<string>()
    while reader.Read() do
        ()
    temp

let readerAsync1 (reader:XmlReader) = 
    async{
        let temp = ResizeArray<string>()
        while reader.Read() do
            ()
        return temp
    }

let readerAsync2 (reader:XmlReader) = 
    async{
        while reader.Read() do
            ()
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let path = @"C:\Temp\LargeTest1000.xlsx"
    use zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead path
    let sheetZipEntry = zipArchive.GetEntry(@"xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml")

    let stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let sheetStream = sheetZipEntry.Open()  // again
    use reader = XmlReader.Create(sheetStream)
    let temp1 = readerNormal reader
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "%A" stopwatch.Elapsed

    System.GC.Collect()

    let stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let sheetStream = sheetZipEntry.Open()  // again
    use reader = XmlReader.Create(sheetStream)
    let temp1 = readerAsync1 reader |> Async.RunSynchronously
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "%A" stopwatch.Elapsed

    System.GC.Collect()

    let stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopwatch.Start()
    let sheetStream = sheetZipEntry.Open()  // again
    use reader = XmlReader.Create(sheetStream)
    readerAsync2 reader |> Async.RunSynchronously
    stopwatch.Stop()
    printfn "%A" stopwatch.Elapsed

    printfn "DONE"
    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

## INFO

1. I am aware that the above Async code does not do any actual Async work - what I a trying to ascertain here is the overhead of simply making it Async
2. I don't expect it to go faster just because I've wrapped it in an Async. My question is the opposite: why the dramatic (IMHO) slowdown.

## TIMINGS

A comment below correctly pointed out that I should provide timings for datasets of various sizes which is implicitly what had led me to be asking this question in the first instance.

The following are some times based on small vs large datasets. While the absolute values are not too meaningful, the relativities are interesting:

30 elements (small dataset)

> Normal: 00:00:00.0006994
>
> Async1: 00:00:00.0036529
>
> Async2: 00:00:00.0014863

(A lot slower but presumably indicative of Async setup costs - this is as expected)

1.5 million elements

> Normal: 00:00:01.5749734
>
> Async1: 00:00:03.3942754
>
> Async2: 00:00:03.3760785

(~ 2x slower. Surprised that the difference in timing is not amortized as the dataset gets bigger. If this is the case, then pipelining/parallelization can only improve performance here if you have more than two cores - to outweigh the overhead that I can't explain...)

Comment: notice how you never use `!` inside the `async` block? That's a huge hint that you don't really need it! - Also Async != Parallel/Multithreaded and even this would not necessary give you more performance - btw: what is "twice as slow"? Did you test it for different file-lengths?

Comment: @Carsten Thanks. I'm planning on using some asynchronous (!) code inside the Async block later (`MailboxProcessor` style). This version is just an attempt for me to estimate the overhead of making it Async to start with. I am surprised by the overhead and trying to understand why.

Comment: Well, you don't give us nearly enough information to really tell you much (beyond the fact that you're using `async` wrong). How long does the function call take? How did you setup your benchmark? How did you setup your testing environment? Did you make sure to run the two implementations in the same environment, including various preheating measures to ensure you do a fair comparison? There's whole books written on the topic of benchmarking - it's a rather complex subject.

Comment: @Luaan Using `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch()` on my local machine and have timed it on multiple runs to confirm. The time difference is very consistent.

Comment: @Sam if you want to compare algorithms you should not only to it multiple times but also for different input(length)s ... remember: you want to find out any constants ...

Comment: How much time does it take to run?

Comment: @Carsten Thanks. I had actually done tests at small and large sizes. I have provided them in the body of the question.

Comment: @Luaan See update to Q

Comment: Can you cut this down to a full, minimal example? I suspect you're doing something awful in the `reader`/`readerAsync` function. Since the overhead seems to not be a fixed time, it might be that you've introduced a need for synchronization somewhere.

Comment: @Luaan minimal example constructed and Question amended.

Comment: Okay, I tested this thoroughly. Seems you are right - the `while` is translated into an asynchronous `while`, giving us overhead for each and every iteration of the loop. And there's a lot of those with `XmlReader.Read`. Ouch :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no asynchronous work to do. In effect, all you get is the overheads and no benefits. `async {}` doesn't mean "everything in the braces suddenly becomes asynchronous". It simply means you have a simplified way of using asynchronous code - but you never call a single asynchronous function!

Additionaly, "asynchronous" doesn't necessarily mean "parallel", and it doesn't necessarily involve multiple threads. For example, when you do an asynchronous request to read a file (which you're *not* doing here), it means that the OS is told what you want to be done, and how you should be notified *when* it is done. When you run code like this using `RunSynchronously`, you're simply blocking one thread while posting asynchronous file requests - a scenario pretty much identical to using synchronous file requests in the first place.

The moment you do `RunSynchronously`, you throw away any reason whatsoever to use asynchronous code in the first place. You're still using a single thread, you just blocked another thread at the same time - instead of saving on threads, you waste one, and add another to do the real work.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I've investigated with the minimal example, and I've got some observations.

1. The difference is absolutely brutal with a profiler on - the non-async version is somewhat slower (up to 2x), but the async version is just never ending. It seems as if a huge number of allocations is going on - and yet, when I break the profiler, I can see that the non-async version (running in 4 seconds) makes a hundred thousand allocations (~20 MiB), while the async version (running over 10 minutes) only makes mere *thousands*. Maybe the memory profiler interacts badly with F# async? The CPU time profiler doesn't have this problem.
2. The generated IL is very different for the two cases. Most importantly, even though our `async` code doesn't actually do anything asynchronous, it creates a ton of async builder helpers, sprinkles a ton of (asynchronous) `Delay` calls through the code, and going into outright absurd territory, each iteration of the loop is an extra method call, including the setup of a helper object.

Apparently, F# automatically translates `while` into an asynchronous `while`. Now, given how well compressed `xslt` data usually is, very little I/O is involved in those `Read` operations, so the overhead absolutely dominates - and since every iteration of the "loop" has its own setup cost, the overhead scales with the amount of data.

While this is mostly caused by the `while` not actually doing anything, it also obviously means that you need to be careful about what you select as `async`, and you need to avoid using it in a case where CPU time dominates (as in this case - after all, both the async and non-async case are almost 100% CPU tasks in practice). This is further worsened by the fact that `Read` reads a single node at a time - something that's relatively trivial even in a big, non-compressed xml file. The overheads absolutely dominate. In effect, this is analogous to using `Parallel.For` with a body like `sum += i` - the setup cost of each of the each of the iterations absolutely dwarfs any actual work being done.

The CPU profiling makes this rather obvious - the two most work intensive methods are:

1. `XmlReader.Read` (expected)
2. `Thread::intermediateThreadProc` - also known as "this code runs on a thread pool thread". The overhead from this in a no-op code like this is around 100% - yikes. Apparently, even though there is no real asynchronicity anywhere, the callbacks are never run synchronously. Every iteration of the loop posts work to a new thread pool thread.

The lesson learned? Probably something like "don't use loops in `async` if the loop body does very little work". The overhead is incurred for each and every iteration of the loop. Ouch.

Comment: First Class answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous code doesn't magically make your code faster. As you've discovered, it'll tend to make isolated code slower, because there's overhead involved with managing the asynchrony.

What it *can* do is to be more *efficient*, but that's not the same as being inherently faster. The main purpose of `Async` is to make Input/Output code more efficient.

If you invoke a 'slow', blocking I/O operation directly, you'll block the thread until the operation returns.

If you instead invoke that slow operation asynchronously, it may free up the thread to do other things. It does require that there's an underlying implementation that's not thread-bound, but uses another mechanism for receiving the response. I/O Completion Ports could be such a mechanism.

Now, if you run a lot of asynchronous code *in parallel*, it may turn out to be faster than attempting to run the blocking implementation in parallel, because the async versions use fewer resources (fewer threads = less memory).

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question to make it clear that I didn't expect the Async version to be faster. My question is more focused on the cause of the Async overhead as dataset size increases for this particular example. +New minimal example provided.